# Font Color Displaying on Chrome Button, but Not Safari

Tags: css, wordpress, forms

There is an embedded form on this WordPress page (by a third party plugin, Genoo) in which I'm trying to re-style. All has gone well aside from the submit button at the bottom. The button should have white text with a black background.

https://lfccworkforce.com/funding-options/fastforward/

It displays fine in Chrome:

[Chrome Sreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QY42F.jpg)

But in Safari it does not:

[Safari Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OoDVC.jpg)

I appreciate everyones help!

```
e.genooForm {
all: unset;
}
.genooForm label {
font-size:.9em;
font-weight: bold;
font-family: Arial, Sans-Serif;
}

.genooForm input.ext-form-input {
border: solid 1px #757575;
width: 100%;
border-radius: 5px;
margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.gn-component--selected {
all: unset;
width: 30% !important;
margin: auto !important;
}

.gn-btn     {
all: unset;
text-align: center;
padding: 10px;
background: #000 !important;
color: #fff !important;
font-size: 1em !important;
font-weight: bold !important;
border-radius: 10px !important;
text-decoration: capitalize !important;
}

.gn-btn:hover {
background:#0176C0 !important;
}

.gn-generated .gn-form .gn-btn {
color: rgb(255, 255, 255)  !important;
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome! Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and modify your question with the relevant code.

Comment: You haven't provided everything that is needed, but guessing there is another stylesheet overriding the style which is why you're trying to use `!important`. If you need `!important` there are other problems (such as specificity) that you need to address. This can be confirmed in the developer console. If you want more in depth help you need to disclose all the stylesheets you are referencing.

Comment: Hm - very strange: The browser inspector in Safari even *shows* `color: #fff !important` as the active color... ? Some JS active here? Can `data-color: transparent` have to do with it?

Comment: The stylesheets utilized on this page is our main one:

https://lfccworkforce.com/wp-content/themes/lfcc_2015/style.css

and the Genoo one for the plugin creating the form:

https://lfccworkforce.com/wp-content/plugins/genoo/assets/GenooFrontend.css

Comment: I suggest removing the `all:unset;` property. Only Safari 9.1 and later support it. Edge doesn't support it at all. Since it resets properties to initial, Safari might be interpreting that property differently from Chrome and setting the color of the button to its default. I don't have a Mac so no way to verify.

Comment: @www139 - That was it! Thank you a ton.

Answer (score 1):

@www139 had the answer:

I suggest removing the all:unset; property. Only Safari 9.1 and later support it. Edge doesn't support it at all. Since it resets properties to initial, Safari might be interpreting that property differently from Chrome and setting the color of the button to its default.